# JPA Criteria API performance Problem JBoss 7.4

Tags: oracle, performance, jpa, jboss, criteria

I am using JPA Criteria API on JBoss EAP 7.4.9 because I must dynamically produce different SQLs according to filters applied on the GUI.
So far this approach has worked, but after adding several millions entries into the Oracle DB the performance has deteriorated so much that the application is unusable.

I have looked at SQL that is produced (there are some Joins in the complete SQL):

```
select * from ( select .... where (component like 'XTA%' ) and (delivered like 'Delivered' ) order by entrytime desc ) where rownum <= 200;
```

This executes in about 30sec.

I have modified the sql in SQLDeveloper by removing the outer select:

```
select ... where (component = '....' ) and (delivered = 'Delivered' ) and rownum <= 200 order by reportmess0_.entrytime desc  ;
```

To my amazement this executes in the lower msec range.

Is there any way to prevent JPA / Criteria API producing this outer select?
Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You do not want to remove the outer query as it is generating an in-line view and should not affect performance.

However, your query:

```sql
select *
from   (
  select ...
  where  (component = '...' )
  and    (delivered = 'Delivered' )
  and    rownum <= 200
  order by entrytime desc
);
```

is (probably) not correct as the `WHERE ... rownum <= 200` filter will be applied before the `ORDER BY` clause so you will be getting the first 200 (randomly selected) rows that match all the `WHERE` filters and then those 200 will be sorted.

If you are paginating the results then what you (probably) want is to sort the result set first and then to get the first 200 rows so you get the rows with the latest date rather than ordering randomly selected rows.

```sql
select *
from   (
  select ...
  where  (component = '...' )
  and    (delivered = 'Delivered' )
  order by entrytime desc
);
where  rownum <= 200
```

But this will be less performant than the first query as it has to order the entire result set and then fetch the latest 200 rows.

Then you can look at techniques to speed up the query such as:

- adding indexes;
- partitioning your tables;
- making the query more efficient by removing joins (although you do not give the query text so we cannot help with this);
- etc.

Comment: It may also help to replace the old-fashioned `rownum` syntax with the more modern `fetch first 200 rows only` syntax. That change won't improve performance, but it will at least avoid the common sorting bug when `rownum` is misused.